# Cambiar el color del label al seleccionar un ChoiceChip en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Tengo el siguiente código de un ChoiceChip, me preguntaba como puedo cambiar el color del Texto al seleccionarlo, se como cambiar el color del background, pero no el del Label, anexo una foto de como se ve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como necesito que se vea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
                    ChoiceChip(
                      label: Text(
                        'Cat2',
                      ),
                      selected: defaultCategoriaIndex == 2,
                      selectedColor: verdeVazel,
                      onSelected: (bool selected) {
                        setState(() {
                          defaultCategoriaIndex = selected ? 2 : 0;
                        });
                      },
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontFamily: 'NeoRegular',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
```

Comment: probaste agregando un style: TextStyle con color para tu Text dentro del `label` ? luego validas según defaultCategoriaIndex y cambias el color

Answer (score 0):

Con tu mimo condición que tienes para saber si esta seleccionada, úsala en el color, debería funcionar y seria algo así:

```
   ChoiceChip(
                  label: Text(
                    'Cat2',
                  ),
                  selected: defaultCategoriaIndex == 2,
                  selectedColor: verdeVazel,
                  onSelected: (bool selected) {
                    setState(() {
                      defaultCategoriaIndex = selected ? 2 : 0;
                    });
                  },
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color:defaultCategoriaIndex == 2?Colors.white:Colors.black,                                   
                      fontFamily: 'NeoRegular',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
```